# Select data from Azure Cosmos and output in Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

There is existed database, collection in my Azure Cosmos. The problem is that I am stuck in how to output the select query data from Azure. The errors are shown me **'TypeError: 'QueryIterable' object is not subscriptable in python'**

How can I output my  from my script ?

```
import pydocumentdb
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client
# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient('https://domain.documents.azure.com:443/', {'masterKey': 'xxxxxxxxx'})
db_id = 'ppDB'
db_query = "select * from c where c.id = '{0}'".format(db_id)
db = list(client.QueryDatabases(db_query))[0]
db_link = db['_self']

coll_id = 'ppCollection'
coll_query = "select * from c where c.id = '{0}'".format(coll_id)
coll = list(client.QueryCollections(db_link, coll_query))
if coll:
    coll = coll[0]
else:
    raise ValueError("Collection not found in database.")
coll_link = coll['_self']

c_id = '121ad45f-a278-3218-d2ba-63aaccd1fbab' 
# Query them in SQL
query = "SELECT * from c where c.id ".format(c_id)     

options = {} 
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = 2
res =client.QueryDocuments(coll_link, query, options)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it the results by changing my code as following.

```
import pydocumentdb;
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

 config = {
'ENDPOINT': 'https://dev.documents.azure.com:443/',
'MASTERKEY': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'ppDb',
'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'ppCollection'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})
# use a SQL based query to get a bunch of documents
query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s where s._ts > 1562173751'}
options = {}
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
options['maxItemCount'] = 2

result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments('dbs/ppDB/colls/ppCollection', query, options)
results = list(result_iterable);
print(results)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to do the same thing, but I kept running to a very similar issue with `ItemPaged` in a different part of the SDK. I also used `list(result_iterable)` and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the python iter() function, for example:

```
res = client.QueryDocuments(coll_link, query, options)

for doc in iter(res):
    print(doc['id'])  #etc.
```

Comment: It didn't print me anything, I also try only with print(whatever) , it also didn't shown. 

when I print out res , it shows me like this - <pydocumentdb.query_iterable.QueryIterable object at 0x0000020BE9C0D668>

can you please help me?

Comment: I think that's because there's a typo in your query.  It should be: query = "SELECT * from c where c.id = '{0}' ".format(c_id).  You currently have: query = "SELECT * from c where c.id ".format(c_id)

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks